# ember.js - application level handling

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling

I have a Ember.js 3.8 app in which I would like application level error handling. I've read what seems to be the [relevant part of the documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.8.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_error-substates) but it doesn't work as I expected.

I have a component to test this with :

**exception-creator.hbs**

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">Development Only - Exception Creator</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Press the button below to create an exception</p>
    <button {{action 'throw' }}>Throw an Exception</button>
  </div>
</div>
{{yield}}
```

**exception-creator.js**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    throw(){
      alert("About to throw an exception");
      throw new Error('Whoops!');
    }
  }
});
```

And (as per my reading of the doco) I have created a route `application-error`

**application-error.hbs**

```
<h1>Error Handler</h1>
<p>This is the error handler</p>
{{outlet}}
```

**application-error.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
});
```

When the button is pressed I expected (after the alert) to be re-routed to the `application-error` template ... but I'm not. What does happen is that the debug console shows "Uncaught Error: Whoops!".

Would someone tell me where I'm going wrong please ?

---

**EDIT**

Having been shown the right path by @stevenelberger I now have a working version which I'm going to put here so that others might benefit from it in the future (not that there's a great deal to it but it might help someone).

I created a new route `exception-testing-route`

**exception-testing-route.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    throw new Error('Whoops - something bad happened at exception-testing-route');
  },
   actions: {
    error(error, transition) {
      console.log("The action 'error' is firing in the route exception-testing-route.");
      console.log("About to return true to bubble the error.");
      return true;
      }
  },
});
```

**exception-testing-route.hbs**

```
{{outlet}}
```

Having the `error` action return true results in the error being bubbled, in this case to the `application-error` route as follows

**application-error.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({

  setupController(controller, error) {
    console.log("application-error setupController firing");
    console.log(error.message);
    this._super(...arguments);
  }

});
```

**application-error.hbs**

```
<h1>Error Handler</h1>
<p>This is the error handler</p>
{{outlet}}
```

Invoking the exception-testing-route results in the following sequence of processing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might have missed this part of the documentation:

> As with the loading substate, **on a thrown error or rejected promise returned from the [...] route's model hook (or beforeModel or afterModel)** Ember will look for an error template or route...

Emphasis added for clarification. Your code is currently throwing an error from an action but Ember will only route to an error state if an error or rejected promise is thrown/returned from a route's `model`, `beforeModel`, or `afterModel` hooks (and potentially from a transition as well although the docs are a little ambiguous on that and I don't have time to test that right now).

So to get to the application-error route you'd need to throw an error or return a rejected promise in some route's `model`, `beforeModel`, or `afterModel` hook.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was indeed the problem. I have provided an edit to the question to illustrate what you showed me. Thanks.